# Tricky double integral split into two parts

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I just cannot get my head around why the two parts of the split integral (5.258) here are equal, or the explanation showing it:
http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uD_zIEEVc7UC&lpg=PA140&ots=9rOgs4ffUT&dq=integral%20of%201%2F(r2-r1)&pg=PA140#v=onepage&q=integral%20of%201/(r2-r1)&f=false

The assertion is that:
$$\int_0^\infty dr_1 r_1^2 e^{-2\alpha r_1/a_0} \left[ \frac{1}{r_1}\int_0^{r_1}dr_2r_2^2e^{-2\alpha r_2/a_0}+ \int_{r_1}^\infty dr_2 r_2 e^{-2\alpha r_2/a_0}\right]$$
equals
$$2\int_0^\infty dr_1 r_1 e^{-2\alpha r_1/a_0} \int_0^{r_1}dr_2r_2^2e^{-2\alpha r_2/a_0}$$
but I can't show it and I don't understand the explanation: "in the second term, interchange dummy variables $r_1$ and $r_2$, then change the order of the two integrals". Can anyone help?

OK... expanding out the square bracket and swapping the dummy variables in the second term:
$$\int_0^\infty dr_1 r_1 e^{-2\alpha r_1/a_0} \int_0^{r_1}dr_2r_2^2e^{-2\alpha r_2/a_0} + \int_0^\infty dr_2 r_2^2 e^{-2\alpha r_2/a_0} \int_{r_2}^\infty dr_1 r_1 e^{-2\alpha r_1/a_0}\\
=\int_0^\infty dr_1 r_1 e^{-2\alpha r_1/a_0} \int_0^{r_1}dr_2r_2^2e^{-2\alpha r_2/a_0} + \int_0^\infty dr_1 r_1 e^{-2\alpha r_1/a_0} \int_0^{r_1}dr_2r_2^2e^{-2\alpha r_2/a_0}\\
= 2\int_0^\infty dr_1 r_1 e^{-2\alpha r_1/a_0} \int_0^{r_1}dr_2r_2^2e^{-2\alpha r_2/a_0}$$
This is OK because in integrating over $x$ from $y$ to $\infty$ and then over $y$ from 0 to $\infty$ is the same as integrating over $y$ from 0 to $x$ and then over $x$ from 0 to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_0^\infty dr_1 r_1^2 e^{-2\alpha r_1/a_0} \left[ \frac{1}{r_1}\int_0^{r_1}dr_2r_2^2e^{-2\alpha r_2/a_0}+ \int_{r_1}^\infty dr_2 r_2 e^{-2\alpha r_2/a_0}\right] \\
=\int_0^\infty dr_1 r_1^2 e^{-2\alpha r_1/a_0} \frac{1}{r_1}\int_0^{r_1}dr_2r_2^2e^{-2\alpha r_2/a_0}+ \int_0^\infty dr_1 r_1^2 e^{-2\alpha r_1/a_0} \int_{r_1}^\infty dr_2 r_2 e^{-2\alpha r_2/a_0}
$$
The hint means that $r_1$ and $r_2$ are just names for the variables of integration, and you can interchange the names in the second term. Simplify and see what you get.

If the limits for $x$ are $0$ and $\infty$ and for $y$ they are $x$ and $\infty$, we are integrating over $(x,y)$ for which $0\leq x \leq y \leq \infty$. Now the limits can be stated such that the limits of $y$ do not depend on $x$ and the limits of $x$ depend on $y$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I've got it (see edit)